# Are there any events dispatched after a user's email confirmation in joomla 3.x?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I need to perform some actions after the user confirms their email accounts/registration. I have been looking for whether Joomla dispatches any events on registration confirmation but i still cant find any. It would be an honor if you guys could help me figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to write a user plugin calling [onUserBeforeSave(...)](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onUserBeforeSave). If the activation field in #__user is changed to "" or 0 from some other value, then I guess the user is beeing activated, and you can take the appropriate action.